# Sending email with images on iPad?

Tags: ipad, email, ios

I've just realized I can't send images from Mail on Ipad.

When a create a new draft there is not add image functionality, so I guess the only way is to email images from Photos.

However, what if I want to send an email with more than one image ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Photo app you can select up to 5 images and hit `Share -> E-Mail`.
Maybe it's possible to mail more then 5 images when you select 5+ and the `Copy` them and `Paste` them in your E-Mail.

See this guide for reference: [Send multiple photos at once on the iPad and iPhone](http://www.macgasm.net/2010/06/29/send-multiple-photos-ipad-iphone/)

Comment: It's worth noting that using the email option will limit you to 5 photos while using copy/paste will get you around that limitation. And I've read somewhere that the email option compresses the image, while copy paste will not.

Answer (score 0):

Tapping on the icon will display more options, such as bulk copy or delete.

[image: Copy option]

Note: I reply becoz I can't add images to @timbooo comment.